# WebDriverError: Session was terminated due to BROWSER_TIMEOUT

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

I'm using selenium for automating the web application. For execution, using Azure Devops.

Sometimes during execution, getting this error message for some scenarios.

> WebDriverError: Session was terminated due to BROWSER_TIMEOUT

I'm not seeing this error locally.

How to resolve this issue? Spent some time in google but no solution yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a grid node's browser is becoming unresponsive.  I think Chrome is more likely to cause this.  You can configure the node's browsertimeout but it may not help if the browser is frozen.  This can also be caused by inactivity of an open webdriver session (which is usually because the browser isn't responding, but could be issues in your code)